# db stringForQuery retrieve one column

Tags: objective-c, fmdb

When using FMResultSet to execute sql, we can use stringForColumn:@"ColumnName" to get the value.

```
FMResultSet *cardInfoList =[db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM holder, cardInfo WHERE holder.userName = ? AND cardInfo.cardNum= holder.cardNum", username];
while ([cardInfoList next]) {
```

But if I use this one: (there is only one record in the database. so its unnecessary to use FMResultSet)
`NSString *s = [db stringForQuery: @"SELECT * FROM holder, cardInfo WHERE holder.cardNum = ? AND cardInfo.cardNum= holder.cardNum", cardNum];`

How to get the value in each column?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your item(s) via following approach:

```
while ([cardInfoList next]) {
   NSString *valueColumn1 = [cardInfoList stringForColumn:@"column1"];
   NSString *valueColumn2 = [cardInfoList stringForColumn:@"column2"];
}
```